# Issue with Azure PowerShell DSC Extension

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I am trying to test PowerShell DSC Extension on Azure VM.

I am trying to download storage blob using built-in File Resource, but it is being treated as a custom resource by the dsc.

Below is the configuration function, that I am sending as zip file to the dsc extension:

```
Configuration Main
{
 param (
        $MachineName,
        $ZipFileUrl
       )

 Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

 Node($MachineName)
 {
      File FileSystemCSVDownload
      {
       DestinationPath = "C:\INI\FileSystem.zip"
       Ensure = "Present"
       SourcePath = $ZipFileUrl
       Type = "Directory"
       Recurse = $true
      }
 }
}
```

I have tried deployment both from the portal as well as using JSON template deployment, but every time it has been treated as a custom resource, and the downloaded zip file is extracted and copied to the `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\modules` folder, and then deleted from the `DSCWork` folder.

**Note:**
When I compile the dsc script manually on the target machine and run it using `Start-dscconfiguration`, it works just fine.

Comment: Few questions, do you have remote execution enabled on the remote system? Do you have Permissions? Is remote script execution allowed, and is the WinRM service running? Try running a basic script like creating a text file in the root drive to see if you can run remote scripts successfully.

Comment: Hi...
As I have mentioned that on compiling the ps1 locally on the VM, the dsc works just fine.
Also, i was able to deploy a dsc configuration successfully using the Json where in a Windows box is getting configured as IIS server but other than that I can't run any other dsc configuration no matter how simple it it.

Comment: care to show the error?